# 2 pass encoding or not?

Tags: video, dvd, encoding

I would like to do a backup of some movies on DVD with **File Factory**.

In the output setting, by default the option **2 pass encoding** is disabled. Do I need to enable it for better quality and does it worth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, 2-pass-encoding will give you better quality (for the same file size). Whether it is worth it is impossible to tell. The actual quality/size gain depends on the material to be encoded (and the encoding). You might save maybe 10%-30% (maintaining identical quality) for average material.

But to really know it, you can only try...

BTW, Wikipedia has a good explanation of the tradeoffs involved in multi-pass encoding: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_bitrate#Multi-pass_encoding_and_single-pass_encoding

Comment: Basically you pay with your time for quality. If you got time, then do 2-pass. That's it.